# Java regex match non printable characters except \n \r and \t

Tags: java, regex

I am an absolute beginner in Regex building but i came across a problem:

User input sometimes contains unusual chars like "xA0" character, and I need it removed.

I tried with

```
string.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "");
```

But it matches new line "\n" character (and i think it matches \r and \t)
Is there a way to exclude those character from matcher??

Thx in advance :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a negated char class.

```
string.replaceAll("[^\\n\\r\\t\\p{Print}]", "");
```

or

```
string.replaceAll("(?![\\n\\r\\t])\\P{Print}", "");
```